# Alternative query for calculating percentage

Tags: sql-server, percentage, query-performance

In SQL Server for calculating percentage I have a function like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fuGetPercentage] ( @part FLOAT, @total FLOAT )
RETURNS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @Result FLOAT = 0, @Cent FLOAT = 100;
    IF (isnull(@total, 0) != 0)
        SET @Result = isnull(@part, 0) * @Cent / @total;
    RETURN @Result
END
```

I wonder that is there any better alternative for that, with same checks and a better calculating percentage like below:

```
SELECT (CASE ISNULL(total, 0) 
            WHEN 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE ISNULL(part, 0) * 100 / total 
        END) as percentage
```

I want to use it directly after `SELECT` like above.

Comment: second logic seems good enough in `SELECT`. Any specific reason why you are using `FLOAT` and not `NUMERIC / DECIMAL`?

Comment: @ughai No.  But I don't want a function I'm searching to find a _simpler_ query like that `SELECT`.

Comment: your logic `select (case isnull(total, 0) when 0 then 0 else isnull(part, 0) * 100 / total end) as percentage` can be directly used in a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use @DmitrijKultasev answer but now, I found that it has two problems:

1. Error on conversion because of the overflow of result of multiply.
2. Performance problem; because of that math multiply and its conversion.

So I change it to this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN total <> 0 AND part <> 0 THEN -- This will return 0 for Null values
            part * 100 / total
        ELSE 
            0
    END AS percentage;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is one issue with using functions such as `ISNULL`. The query will not use indexes in that case. If the beauty of the code isn't in the first place then you can do something like that:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN total * part <> 0 /* will check that both total and part are not null and != 0*/ 
           THEN part * 100 / total
         ELSE 0
    END AS percentage;
```